# Doctrine custom repository chaining filters?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

What is the right way to chain custom repository methods in order to create one composed query that returns the entities based on multiple conditions.

Here is what I did:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ingredientRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    private $query;

    public function initNewQuery()
    {
       $this->query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')->join('i.product', 'p');
       return $this;
    }

    public function clearQuery()
    {
       $this->query = null;
       return $this;
    } 

    public function getResult(){
      $r = $this->query->getQuery()->getResult();
      $this->clearQuery();
      return $r;
    }

    public function filterByProductName( $productName )
    {

      if(!$this->query) $this->initNewQuery();

      $this->query->andWhere('p.name LIKE :name')->setParameter('name', '%'.$productName.'%');

      return $this;
    }

    public function filterByMinContenu( $contenu )
    {

      if(!$this->query) $this->initNewQuery();

      $this->query->andWhere('p.contenu > :contenu')->setParameter('contenu', $contenu);

      return $this;
    }

    public function filterByType( $type ){

      if(!$this->query) $this->initNewQuery();

      $this->query->andWhere('i.type = :type')->setParameter('type', $type);

      return $this;

    }      

}
```

This allows me to do things like:

```
$ingredients = $em->getRepository('ingredient')->initNewQuery()->filterByType(4)->getResult();

$ingredients = $em->getRepository('ingredient')->initNewQuery()->filterByProductName('ell')->filterByMinContenu(10)->getResult();
```

Which is exactly what I want !
But ... I don't really like it.
First, this is not how the default methods like `findBy` and so on work. These all return the results directly. So that doesn't seem right to mix those two behaviours.
And secondly, when calling only the `filterByType` method and then return the results, the query will use a join that it doesn't need. I guess I could find a way to do the join only if I need it, but again, doesn't seem right.

Any ideas on how to do this clean an simple ?

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer without testing:)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ingredientRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    private $query;

    private function initNewQuery()
    {
        $this->query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
    }

    public function findBy($filterArray)
    {
        $this->initNewQuery();
        if (array_key_exists('productName', $filterArray)) {
            $this->filterByProductName($filterArray['productName']);
        }
        if (array_key_exists('minContenu', $filterArray)) {
            $this->filterByMinContenu($filterArray['minContenu']);
        }
        if (array_key_exists('type', $filterArray)) {
            $this->filterByType($filterArray['type']);
        }
        return $this->query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    private function filterByProductName($productName)
    {
        $this->query->join('i.product', 'p');
        $this->query->andWhere('p.name LIKE :name')->setParameter('name', '%'.$productName.'%');
    }

    private function filterByMinContenu($contenu)
    {
        $this->query->andWhere('p.contenu > :contenu')->setParameter('contenu', $contenu);
    }

    private function filterByType($type)
    {
        $this->query->andWhere('i.type = :type')->setParameter('type', $type);
    }
}
```

call:

```
$ingredients = $em->getRepository('ingredient')->findBy(['type'=>4]);

$ingredients = $em->getRepository('ingredient')->findBy(['productName'=>'ell', 'minContenu' => 10]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. But there is still no solution for the unnecessary "join" ? Any ideas on that ?

Comment: i updated the answer. It was a typo.:) Now it is joined only if the production filter exists.